# Is anything know about primes based on $2^{n!} \pmod {n!}$ (I call them Prolonged Primes)?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

***Context***:
*I wanted a function that with a high prime probability and a small factor for the composites so it is less hard to find large primes.
After testing several functions I found combinations with powers of 2 work well and the best result is what I call the prolonged primes:*
$$
\\2^{n!}\pmod{n!}+n!+1
$$
variants:
$$2^{n!}\pmod{n!}+n!+2^m-1  $$
$$a \cdot 2^{n!}\pmod{n!}+b \cdot n!+2^m-1$$
$$a \cdot 2^{n!}\pmod{n!}+ \frac{n!}{b}+2^m-1$$

Each set $(n>5)$ of two consecutive prolonged primes in a sequence has a number of identical end-digits. This number increases as the sequence grow (every 5 multiple adds a zero to $n!$)

Computing $2^{n!}\pmod{n!}$ is a computationally heavy process.
I was able to reduce it to a single computation by calculating each new value from the previous. This is no problem since I use them in sequence.

$\\ \begin{array}{ | l | l |}
    \hline
1 & 2 \\ \hline
2 & 3 \\ \hline
3 & 11 \\ \hline
4 & 41 \\ \hline
5 & 137 \\ \hline
6 & 1217 \\ \hline
7 & 9137 \\ \hline
8 & 44417 \\ \hline
9 & 649217 \\ \hline
11 & 70322177 \\ \hline
12 & 868658177 \\ \hline
16 & 29788541157377 \\ \hline
31 & 8311220533609027825399821947109377 \\ \hline
33 & 10155294119789165784898744415867109377 \\ \hline
36 & 387364270951699233844356032791115387109377 \\ \hline
69 & 214295430044821236016074261674024831070647961292 \\ \hline
    & 488717936328996973257865003235614591740081787109377 \\ \hline
102 & 14029713630648880286922062815894102952061448710216249134122221201026544408 \\ \hline
    & 63248150250874759143759712703754778763863251960131100522882946180022607743 \\ \hline
    & 740081787109377 \\ \hline
123 & 1396125414362540036586288750486661181818415438916038025815174387517031264 \\ \hline
    & 8802665413781726415356482086077786679179682307758994668096365965456797486 \\ \hline
    & 585624859303412760755434524498613380022607743740081787109377 \\ \hline
129 & 5158313427248877432707689536601345083943420563887232269890016333854378227 \\ \hline
    & 0801740010391017979325112022180257787026737207921189915153931895232079890 \\ \hline
    & 063141377305212344519939677313272668097075893380022607743740081787109377 \\ \hline
\end{array}$

All my record primes are prolonged primes. I was able to find a prime of 118,000 digits on a single computer after about 30,000 calculations.
Questions:
Is anything known about these 'prolonged' primes?
Is there more than the 2 power that makes this a good function for primes?
I guess the mod function helps but I don't see how?

Comment: Elaborate what you call prolonged primes. The "best results are called prolonged primes": what are considered the best results?

Comment: Prolonged primes = primes based on $2^{n!} \pmod {n!}$ (I meant this was the best function I found based a power of 2)

Comment: And best means the best fitting the description given in the context.

Comment: How did you determine that the 118,000 digit numbers were prime?

Comment: I used OpenPFGW, it uses a Pocklington test when (most) of the Factorizationof $(p-1)$ is known. The prolonged prime with $+1$  the -1 is easy to factorize, for the prolonged primes with $-1$ the $+1$ is factorize (openPFGW acn use for both).